# Apache Tomcat load balancing file replica

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing

We have two apache servers for load balancing. Whenever I upload a file on one server. Using load balancing concepts, will it get copied into other server.

Do these two server maintain replica of each other?
If not, how to do that? How to maintain the replica of one another servers?
If Yes, what configuration is required.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancing balances the requests that are sent to a load balancer to the server that actually answers them.

Handling files that are uploaded to one server is on the application level - it must be handled by your application - e.g. through storing it in a location that all nodes can access (filesystem, database).

There's nothing that tomcat or an appserver can do for you - because they don't know what needs to be replicated and what doesn't. They don't know if something that you uploaded will be processed and can be forgotten, or if it will be stored for later download.